# Daphne showing blank screen on browser with Django ASGI, unable to load static files. Why?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

When I run the server using :-

```
python manage.py runserver
```

everything is working correctly, but for the hosting purpose I have to run it with daphne which is not working correctly. Its not giving any error but showing blank screen because it is not loading static files even though I have specified STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.

**asgi.py**
[image: This is asgi.py]

**settings.py**
[image: settings.py]

**command view**
[image: command view]

**browser showing blank screen**
[image: Browser View]

Help me fixing it, its been so long I am searching for the solution but unable to figure out any. if anything else required in question comment me, I will re-edit for the same.

EDIT:
I have tried by collecting all static files in same directory and providing STATIC_ROOT in settings. For  this I have done the following:

1. provided STATIC ROOT in settings.py
2. python manage.py collectstatic

But the problem is still same.
[image: settings.py]

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production. You have to server them yourself. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: I have re-edited the question, please recheck it.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you ran collectstatic, Django doesn't serve static files in production. You have to configure Nginx or Apache or something else to serve them.

Comment: `django` serves `static/media` files only in `DEBUG` mode. In normal mode you have to configure `Nginx` or `Apache` to server `static/media` files - they will do it faster,safer  and using less CPU - and this can be important when you pay for CPU and hackers may attack server, and users may expect to load page in less then 3 seconds.

Comment: I have already deployed 2-3 django projects that are based on wsgi. They didn't require me to configure Apache for static files. But with asgi I am doing for the first time and problems are arising with static files not with the server. Can you give detailed solution of what i have to do ? Because those project which i have hosted are working fine with same settings.